# Run software even after closing the terminal

Tags: linux, services, systemd

I do have a server installed which I always need to run in terminal. The command looks like

```
software server
```

Now i want this to run in the background without the need to keep the window open.
I thought about creating a service.
My software.service looks like

```
[Unit]
Description=Software Server

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/software/bin/software server
```

However. In all services and and guides a ExecStop needs to be defined. How do I do this without the server really supporting it? Can I just kill the process on stop?

Any suggestion how I can solve my issue (doesn't have to be a service)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Relevant bit, emphasis mine:

> ExecStop=
>
> Commands to execute to stop the service started via ExecStart=. This argument takes multiple command lines, following the same scheme
> as described for ExecStart= above. **Use of this setting is optional.**
> After the commands configured in this option are run, it is implied
> that the service is stopped, and any processes remaining for it are
> terminated according to the KillMode= setting (see systemd.kill(5)).
> **If this option is not specified, the process is terminated by sending
> the signal specified in KillSignal= or RestartKillSignal= when service
> stop is requested.** Specifier and environment variable substitution is
> supported (including $MAINPID, see above).
>
> Note that it is usually not sufficient to specify a command for this setting that only asks the service to terminate (for example, by
> sending some form of termination signal to it), but does not wait for
> it to do so. Since the remaining processes of the services are killed
> according to KillMode= and KillSignal= or RestartKillSignal= as
> described above immediately after the command exited, this may not
> result in a clean stop. The specified command should hence be a
> synchronous operation, not an asynchronous one.

And https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html# tells us:

> Defaults to SIGTERM.

So: if you don't specify the ExecStop and run `systemctl stop software_server` SystemD will do the equivalent of `kill -15` .